# how to add and remove specific attribute values

Tags: angular

In angular it is possible to add and remove class attribute values from an element by specifying a boolean that is bound to a specific variable in the controller:

```
@HostBinding('class.value-1') value1 = true;
```

Is it possible to do the same for other attributes? Similar to below (which does not work)

```
 @HostBinding('attr.data-custom.value-1') value1 = true;
```

Comment: What attribute do you expect to get for attr.data-custom.value-1? That doesn’t seem valid?

Comment: attribute value "value-1" will be added to attribute "data-custom".
Meaning if value1 field has a value of true, then data-custom="something1 value-1 something2" is a valid value for data-custom attribute. If value1 is false then value-1 will be removed from the value list of data-custom attribute values.
The idea is exactly the same as for the class attribute.

Answer (score -1):

you can use ViewChild to do this,
here's a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdvfcn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)